# How Can I Change the Format of a File input by the User

Tags: python-3.x

I am given a file that has contents that look like this:

```
Year,Value
1880,-1.56
1881,-0.08
1882,-0.30
1883,-1.44
```

And this is what it should look like after it goes through my code:

```
Temperature anomaly filename:SacramentoTemps.csv
1880 -1.56
1881 -0.08
1882 -0.3
1883 -1.44
```

So it should ignore the "Year,Value" header. I need to use strip() to remove the newline charace and split() to extract the year and temperature to seperate strings. However, my code doesn't print anything.

This is my code:

```
filename = input("Temperature anomaly filename:")

infile = open(filename)

infile = str(infile)

for line in  infile:
    line = line.strip()

print(filename)
print(infile.replace(",", " "))
```

The for statement is suppose to remove the header and I used replace() instead of split(). replace() doesn't work here so I would prefer a solution using split(). I'd also be grateful there is an explanation do I understand the problem.

Comment: You are just converting a csv to a tsv , is that so ?>

Comment: Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read the input file. You would then get each row as a list of values.